# Synonym request: galaxy-note-3

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, retag-request

[galaxy-note-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-note-3) and [samsung-galaxy-note-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-note-3) should be synonymized and merged.

Although the former currently has more questions, the latter matches our naming convention.

Comment: Well, that was fast.

Comment: But instead of *furious*, *obvious* – no discussion needed :)